# Setting parameters from a csv file

Tags: python, arrays, csv, opencsv

I am trying to read from a csv file and set some values to a power supply. My main purpose is to set the values for a certain amount of time, and then after the desired time has passed, it should set the next value after it. I am really new to the whole programming world, so I can understand what is written, but am not being able to fix it.

What is happening is that my program is being able to read the first value in my file, but is not jumping to the next value after the set time has passed. So it keeps on running at the first value stated and doesn't even terminate the program. Please advise. Thank you.

Find my program below:

```
with open('example_profile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    dataset = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(dataset)
    rows = list(dataset)
    inputSamples = np.empty([len(rows), 2], dtype=float)
    testStartTime = time.time()
    for idx, data in enumerate(rows):
        inputSamples[idx] = [data[0], data[1]]
        s.sendall('VOLT {0}\n'.format(data[0]).encode('utf-8'))
        stopTime = testStartTime + int(data[1])
        while time.time() < stopTime:
            s.sendall('MEAS:ALL?\n'.encode('utf-8'))
            [curr, volt, res, pwr] = (s.recv(1024)).split(',')
            outputSamples[iSample] = ([round(float(curr), 2), round(float(volt), 2), round(time.time() - testStartTime, 2)])
            iSample += 1
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: you're probably stuck on this line `[curr, volt, res, pwr] = (s.recv(1024)).split(',')` try adding [a timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) and see if you hit the timeout

Comment: yes it seems you are right this might be it. I tried commenting the last 3 lines before time.sleep() and it works